# Incorrect operation of the WinAPI screen coordinates. There may be problems with HDC

Tags: c, winapi

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

typedef unsigned int ui;

void GetSizeWindow(ui*, ui*);
void GetCenterWindow(ui*, ui*);

int main()
{
    HDC hdcwin = GetDC(NULL);
    ui x_center = 0, y_center = 0;
    POINT cours;
    GetSizeWindow(&x_center, &y_center);
    while (1)
    {
        system("cls");
        for (ui x_center1 = 0; x_center1 < x_center; x_center1++)
        {
            SetPixelV(hdcwin, x_center1, y_center / 2, RGB(0, 255, 0));
        }
        GetCursorPos(&cours);
        printf("(%d ; %d)\n", cours.x, cours.y);
        printf("[DEBUG] (%d ; %d)\n", x_center, y_center);

    }
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcwin);
    return 0;
}

void GetSizeWindow(ui* x, ui* y)
{
    *x = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFULLSCREEN);
    *y = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFULLSCREEN);
}

void GetCenterWindow(ui *x, ui *y)
{
    GetSizeWindow(x, y);
    *x /= 2;
    *y /= 2;
}
```

Initially, the goal was just to draw a pixel in the center of the screen. Everything seems to be correct, divide the width and height by 2, but the pixel is drawn far from the center. I decided to check how correct my coordinate plane is by drawing a line along the entire length of the screen. It turns out that for some reason part of the width is not used at all. The same problem with height. What is the problem? How do I get the center pixel on the screen?

Comment: Your app is likely not DPI-aware (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows), so the OS will lie to you about things like screen coordinates and window sizes

Comment: GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFULLSCREEN) doezn't account for things like the Task bar.  You really shouldn't be trying to access the Desktop hDC directly. You should create a fullscreen Window.

Comment: And with SM_CXSCREEN and SM_CYSCREEN ?

Comment: Also, you don't get to draw on somebody else's window. If you want to paint something you have to do it on your own window.